# Compile-time C++ function to check whether all template argument types are unique

Tags: c++, overloading, variadic-templates, multiple-inheritance, c++20

There is a nice question ([Which substitution failures are not allowed in requires clauses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59555623/which-substitution-failures-are-not-allowed-in-requires-clauses)) proposing the next problem.

One needs to write a compile-time function `template<typename... Ts> constexpr bool allTypesUnique()` that will return `true` if all argument types are unique, and `false` otherwise. And the restriction is *not to compare the argument types pairwise*. Unfortunately, the answer only explains why such function cannot be implemented with some particular approach.

I think the solution can be achieved using multiple inheritance. The idea is to make a class inherited from a number of classes: one for each type `T` in `Ts`. And each such class defines a virtual function with a signature depending on `T`. If some `T` is found more than once in `Ts` then function `f` in a child class will override the function in a base class and it can be detected:

```
template<typename> struct A{};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct B : B<Ts...> {
    using B<Ts...>::f;
    constexpr virtual void f(A<T>, bool & unique) { if( ++count > 1 ) unique = false; }
    int count = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct B<T> {
    constexpr virtual void f(A<T>, bool & unique) { if( ++count > 1 ) unique = false; }
    int count = 0;
};

template<typename... Ts>
constexpr bool allTypesUnique() {
    B<Ts...> b;
    bool res = true;
    ( b.f( A<Ts>{}, res ), ... );
    return res;
}

int main() {
    static_assert( allTypesUnique<void>() );
    static_assert( allTypesUnique<void, int&>() );
    static_assert( !allTypesUnique<int&, int&>() );
    static_assert( allTypesUnique<char, short, int>() );
    static_assert( !allTypesUnique<char, short, char>() );
}
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8jhnE7P11

Just curious, is the solution correct and is there a simpler solution for this problem?

Comment: I added the C++20 tag because, before that, `virtual` functions could not be `constexpr`.

Comment: FWIW, MSVC gives loads of warnings (mostly trivial, about non-virtual destructors) and clang-cl chokes completely on your code (maybe it's not yet fully C++20 compliant).

Comment: This breaks when given a reference type, but it should be easy to fix.

Comment: Why a restriction that you cannot compare argument types pairwise? It seems pretty arbitrary. Is this purely an academic exercise?

Comment: Why is it important/useful to avoid pairwise comparison? Note you did not write "Avoid all-pairs comparisons", you require complete avoidance of such comparisons. This preculdes using an `std::is_same_v`-based approach.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I made a minor code change to support reference types.

Comment: Usually, these type of exercises are artificial in the sense that you probably need later a general transformation associated (in this case "remove duplicates"). Some times the general problem ("remove duplicates") is easier than the restricted problem ("find if the list has unique elements"). General problems of these types are well tackled by Boost.MPL or Boost.MP11, I used `mpl::fold<mpl::vector<T...>, mpl::set<>, mpl::insert<mpl::_1, mpl::_2>>` to remove duplicates in my library https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-covariant/-/blob/master/detail/result_of_set.hpp#L28-38

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use virtual base classes depending on each of the given types, you will get exact one base class instance for every unique type in the resulting class. If the number of given types is the number of generated base classes, each type was unique. You can "measure" the number of generated base classes by its size but must take care that you have a vtable pointer inside which size is implementation dependent. As this, each generated type should be big enough to hide alignment problems.

BTW: It works also for reference types.

```
template < typename T> struct AnyT { char i[128]; };

template < typename FIRST, typename ... T>
struct CheckT: virtual AnyT<FIRST>, virtual CheckT<T...> { };

template < typename FIRST >
struct CheckT<FIRST>: virtual AnyT<FIRST> {};


template < typename ... T>
constexpr bool allTypesUnique()
{
    using T1 = CheckT<int>;
    using T2 = CheckT<bool, int>;

    constexpr std::size_t s1 = sizeof( T1 );
    constexpr std::size_t s2 = sizeof( T2 );
    constexpr std::size_t diff = s2 - s1; 
    constexpr std::size_t base = s1 - diff;
    constexpr std::size_t measure = sizeof( CheckT< T...> );

    return !((sizeof...(T)*diff+base) - measure);
}


int main() {
    static_assert( allTypesUnique<void>() );
    static_assert( allTypesUnique<void, int>() );
    static_assert( !allTypesUnique<void, void>() );
    static_assert( allTypesUnique<char, short, int>() );
    static_assert( !allTypesUnique<char, short, char>() );
}
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Whbvfohhv)

Answer (score 5):

A simpler solution can be obtained in compilers supporting class size optimization via C++20 attribute [[[no_unique_address]]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) for empty members. If all class empty members have distinct types, then its `sizeof` will be 1. If some member types are repeating then they cannot share the same address and `sizeof` will be more than 1.

Solution code:

```
template<typename> struct A{};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct B : B<Ts...> {
    [[no_unique_address]] A<T> a;
};

template<typename T>
struct B<T> {
    [[no_unique_address]] A<T> a;
};

template<typename... Ts>
constexpr bool allTypesUnique() {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts) <= 1 )
        return true;
    else
        return sizeof(B<Ts...>) == 1;
}

int main() {
    static_assert( allTypesUnique<void>() );
    static_assert( allTypesUnique<void, int&>() );
    static_assert( !allTypesUnique<int&, int&>() );
    static_assert( allTypesUnique<char, short, int>() );
    static_assert( !allTypesUnique<char, short, char>() );
}
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/577EP1774

Answer (score 3):

A single `constexpr` function can be constructed to answer this question:

```cpp
template <class T, class... Ts>
constexpr bool unique_types()
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts)) {
        return !(std::is_same_v<T,Ts> || ...) && unique_types<Ts...>();
    }
    return true;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7132f620f8b64a2)

the code above is the compile time equivalent of

```cpp
for (int i(0); i < n; ++i)
  for (int j(i + 1); j < n; ++j)
    { /* check type[i] vs type[j] */ }
```

If you want any variation in comparison (e.g. consider `int` same as `int&`) just modify the `std::is_same_v` (e.g. `std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, std::decay_t<Ts>>`)

Comment: the OP has explicitly stated that `the restriction is not to compare the argument types pairwise`.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik I'm mostly concerned with the `is there a simpler solution for this problem?` part

Comment: `the restriction is not to compare the argument types pairwise` excludes your solution from a set of possible solutions to compare between for `is there a simpler solution for this problem?`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to elaborate on using compile-time type ids.
Here is a partly implemented C++14 version (compile-time sorting is required):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace detail {
    template<typename T>
    struct type_id {
        constexpr static int value{};
    };

    template<const int *const A, const int *const B>
    struct same_address : std::false_type {};

    template<const int *const A>
    struct same_address<A, A> : std::true_type {};

}// namespace detail

// TODO: implement
template<const int *const... I>
struct sort_array {
    using type = std::integer_sequence<const int *const, I...>;
};

template<typename>
struct find_duplicates;

template<const int *const A, const int *const B, const int *const... I>
struct find_duplicates<std::integer_sequence<const int *const, A, B, I...>> {
    constexpr static bool value = std::conditional_t<detail::same_address<A, B>::value,
                                                     std::true_type,
                                                     find_duplicates<std::integer_sequence<const int *const, B, I...>>>::value;
};

template<>
struct find_duplicates<std::integer_sequence<const int *const>> {
    constexpr static bool value = false;
};

template<const int *const I>
struct find_duplicates<std::integer_sequence<const int *const, I>> {
    constexpr static bool value = false;
};

template<typename... T>
constexpr bool all_types_unique() {
    return !find_duplicates<typename sort_array<&detail::type_id<T>::value...>::type>::value;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(detail::same_address<&detail::type_id<int>::value,
                                       &detail::type_id<int>::value>::value,
                  "");
    static_assert(!detail::same_address<&detail::type_id<int>::value,
                                        &detail::type_id<double>::value>::value,
                  "");

    static_assert(all_types_unique<>(), "");
    static_assert(all_types_unique<int>(), "");
    static_assert(all_types_unique<int, double>(), "");
    static_assert(all_types_unique<int, double, char>(), "");
    static_assert(!all_types_unique<int, int>(), "");
    static_assert(!all_types_unique<int, int, int>(), "");

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/E4G6YchE5

Comment: @Fedor I removed that from the answer.