# How can I make sure a type only appear once in a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have an alias:

```
using bar = foo<string, string, int>;
```

How can I make sure that "string" only appear once in the parameter? If it appears more than once then throw an error.

I have made a function to count how many times a type appeared in the parameter but failed to implement the idea.

```
template <class T> 
constexpr std::size_t type_count_impl(std::size_t count = 0) {
    return count;
};

template <class T, class T1, class... Types>
constexpr std::size_t type_count_impl(std::size_t count = 0) {
    return type_count_impl<T, Types...>(count + (std::is_same<T, T1>::value ? 1 : 0));
};

template <class T, class... Types> 
constexpr std::size_t type_count() {
    return type_count_impl<T, Types...>();
};
```

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69236476/7325599

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a simple compile time error if *any* type in the variadic parameter pack is duplicated, it's pretty simple:

```
template <typename T> struct Base{};
template <typename... Ts> struct NoDuplicates : Base<Ts>... { 
    constexpr operator bool() const { return true; }
};
```

That's it, and if it's what you need it will compile faster than any recursive template metaprogramming, fold expression, or type-trait approach.  In fact, I know of no faster technique at compile time.
This works because a class is not allowed to inherit from the same base class twice.  The reason it inherits from `Base<T>` instead of just `T`, is in case T is a type you can't inherit from, such as a primitive integral value, or an array, or void, etc.

To use:

```
template <typename... Ts>
class Foo {
    static_assert(NoDuplicates<Ts...>{}); 
};

Foo<int, char, int> foo; // ERROR (see below)
```

```
<source>:3:34: error: duplicate base type 'Base<int>' invalid
    3 | template <typename... Ts> struct NoDuplicates : Base<Ts>... {
```

---

Now, if you *don't* want a compile error, but want to compute a boolean indicating if there are any duplicates, it's a little more complicated, but not too bad.  Comments show the 3 cases to check:

```
template <typename T, typename... Rest>
constexpr bool hasDuplicates() {
    // Check T against each item in Rest, and if any match we have duplicates
    if ((std::is_same_v<T, Rest> || ...)) 
        return true;
    
    // Is there anything left to check in Rest?  If not, no duplicates.
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Rest) == 0)
        return false;

    // T isn't duplicated, but is anything in Rest duplicated?
    return hasDuplicates<Rest...>();
}
```

It can be used similarly:

```
template <typename... Ts>
class Foo {
    static_assert(not hasDuplicates<Ts...>()); 
};

Foo<int, std::string, std::string> foo; // Error, there are dupes
```

---

And finally, if you only care if a specific type is duplicated, it is even easier:

```
// Check if Needle is found 2 or more times in this Haystack
template <typename Needle, typename... Haystack>
constexpr bool hasDuplicateInList() {
    return ((std::is_same_v<Needle, Haystack> + ...)) > 1;
}
```

As far as "throwing" goes, if that's what you want, you can always throw an exception if you detect the boolean having a disallowed value in a normal `if`

Answer (score 0):

Your `type_count_impl()` does not need to accept an argument, just simply return `0` when the size of `Types...` is `0`. So your `type_count()` can be simplified to:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T> 
constexpr std::size_t type_count() {
  return 0;
};

template <class T, class T1, class... Types>
constexpr std::size_t type_count() {
  return type_count<T, Types...>() + std::is_same<T, T1>::value;
};

#include <string>

static_assert(type_count<std::string, std::string, std::string, int>() == 2);
static_assert(type_count<int, std::string, std::string, int>() == 1);
static_assert(type_count<int>() == 0);
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/693er3GTx)